# How to merge different lists with the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x

Results returned by query database

```
["www.google.com","2019-1-2","102"],
["www.fb.com","2019-1-4","292"],
["www.amazon.com","2019-3-2","142"],
["www.google.com","2019-6-2","162"],
["www.fb.com","2019-8-2","52"],
["www.fb.com","2019-3-2","522"],
["www.google.com","2019-8-5","591"]
```

The list style results I want:

```
["www.google.com",["2019-1-2","102"],["2019-6-2","162"],["2019-8-5","591"]],
["www.fb.com",["2019-1-4","292"],["2019-8-2","52"],["2019-3-2","522"]],
["www.amazon.com",["2019-3-2","142"]]
```

Or a dictionary style.

```
{"www.google.com":[["2019-1-2","102"],["2019-6-2","162"],["2019-8-5","591"]]},
{"www.fb.com":[["2019-1-4","292"],["2019-8-2","52"],["2019-3-2","522"]]},
["www.amazon.com":["2019-3-2","142"]}
```

Try to compare the first element of the list

```
temp = arr[0]
for x in result:
    if x[0] == temp
```

Comment: You probably want just one dict as output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a `defaultdict` and some list splicing

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

db = [["www.google.com","2019-1-2","102"],
      ["www.fb.com","2019-1-4","292"],
      ["www.amazon.com","2019-3-2","142"],
      ["www.google.com","2019-6-2","162"],
      ["www.fb.com","2019-8-2","52"],
      ["www.fb.com","2019-3-2","522"],
      ["www.google.com","2019-8-5","591"]]

for d in db:
    data[d[0]].append(d[1:])

print(data)
```

will print

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'www.amazon.com': [['2019-3-2', '142']],
         'www.fb.com': [['2019-1-4', '292'],
          ['2019-8-2', '52'],
          ['2019-3-2', '522']],
         'www.google.com': [['2019-1-2', '102'],
          ['2019-6-2', '162'],
          ['2019-8-5', '591']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for x, y, z in l:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append([y, z])
print(d)
```

Or use a one-liner dictionary comprehension:

```
print({x: [[j, k] for i, j, k in l if i == x] for x, y, z in l})
```